# Expected 2-3 arguments but got 4 in angular while performing POST operation?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a form and when i click the submit button **onSubmit()** function is called and here i have printed in console all the datas that are needed to be passed through component class like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log("entered in submiteed");
    console.log(this.selectedTable);
    console.log(this.documents);
    console.log(this.empList);

    this.letter.inOut="AnnexOne";
    this.letter.letterFile=null;
    this.letter.representativeName=null;
    this.letter.assessmentNo=0;
    this.letter.letterIssuedSubBy=null;
    console.log(this.letter);
      this.letterService.saveThree(this.selectedTable,this.documents,this.empList).subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
  }
```

The JSON data that is printed in console is like:

[image]

I tried to send the three parameters from here **saveThree(this.selectedTable,this.documents,this.empList)**

and send it to service class,so i need to perform post operation so i tried :

```
export class LetterService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/letter';
   private letter = new Letter();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


 saveThree(selectedTable: any,documents: any,empList: any): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/create`, selectedTable,documents,empList);
  }

}
```

In this class also i have used three parameters to receive but the error is :

[image]

I need to pass these three parameters from service class to backend but Why it is me showing me such mismatch error though there are equal number of parameters?

Comment: Read the [API documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient). It should clarify this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because POST request has three parameters(first is URL,second is DATA that you need to pass and third is optional which is header information).If you want to pass more than one data then you need to like below.

```
return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/create`, {selectedTable,documents,empList})}
```

Answer (score 2):

because post request takes 3 parameters(`URL`, `DATA` object that you need to send, and `HttpOptions` object if you need to send additional options), 
you are sending here `selectedTable` as `Data` object, `documents` as `HttpOptions` object, and `empList` just as 4th argument, to solve this  just add that 3 objects in one and send as one object (as second parameter `DATA`)

```
  export class LetterService {

      private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/letter';
       private letter = new Letter();

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


     saveThree(selectedTable: any,documents: any,empList: any): Observable<Object> {
        return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/create`, {selectedTable: selectedTable,documents: documents, empList: empList});
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Http `POST` takes resource **URL** as a parameter and additional two paramters

1. the **Data** to POST in the body of the request
2. the method **HttpOptions** (if any)

For example :

```
addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero))
    );
}
```

in your **.ts**

```
saveThree(selectedTable: any,documents: any,empList: any): Observable<Object> {
    let _data = { 
       "selectedTable" : selectedTable,
       "documents" : documents,
       "empList"  : empList 
    }
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}` + `/create`, _data );
  }
```

Comment: where i need to add this please illustrate me

Comment: @ashwinkarki You should wrap all your data into an object and use the same at your backend to retrieve the data.